# Android logcat errors

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Android, but not new to Java, and I am experienced with Eclipse.
However, I just installed the newest Android SDK from developer.Android.com and installed 
in Eclipse 4.2 Java EE version with latest ADT.

I went through the tutorial about installation, and ran the Hello World example in an emulator.

The app seems to run fine.

The Console output looks OK, But the LogCat is crazy with RED.

Here's an example of some of the errors it outputs during a running session:

> Failed to open libwvm.so
>     Failed to extract an album art
>     Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>     batteryVoltagePath not found
>     error loading /system/meida/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
>     runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin […]
>     at java.util.concurrent.threadpoolExecutor.runWorker […]
>     Illegal state exception
>     Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator

**Note:** I don't expect anyone to debug this since it's a jumble, AND there's nothing to debug since I didn't code anything! I just want to know if this behavior is normal for the logcat when using an emulator.

I've never seen this amount of errors and warnings on a simple Hello World, especially when it seems to run just fine.

If you're wondering, I followed the tutorial on ["Installing the SDK"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) to a tee.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty common to see many errors in android emulator logcat, unfortunately.  I wouldn't worry about this unless you are having problems with your app.

Comment: I just worry that this is an indication that my development environment is not set up correctly - like I was missing packages or something.  Does it do this with real android devices?  Or just the emulator?

Comment: You'll get a surprising number of errors even on real devices, but generally less than the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Since logcat logs all the events happening on your device including touch events or accessing google apis that are needed to background sync your phone. So it will show you some errors in red. That is normal, if there is any problem with your application, it will point out to that error prone line with its line number.

Comment: OK, thanks for the replies, I thought maybe there was something wrong with my development environment or some google packages were missing or something like that.  The most curious error, was this: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)  - That error showed up the most and now I'm wondering what this trace file is and how could I get it to create one.  Sounds like a similar trace file used in flash programming.